# Getting multi records from check boxes

Tags: php, mysqli

First of all before anyone here regrets and set this duplicate I don't know will be or not but I tried to search alot but wasn't able to find my answer I created a table from which there are some checkboxes what I want to do is if someone selects 3 entries then the data will be exported for those 3 entries only this is y query what I have done so far

```
$id = $_POST['select'];
    foreach($id as $key) {
        echo $key . ", ";

    }

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE uid IN ('$key')") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

I dont know why it's giving me the last record only ? it should have given me 3 records like happens in between query it give us the entries of d between 1 and 3 but what if we select id 1 3 5 it shoulld have given these 3 right so for exporting it to excel i did this code found some help working fine but having issue with my query not successful

```
if($num_rows >= 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach ($row as $name => $value)
            {
                $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $name);
                $comma = ",";
            }

        $seperator .= "\n";
        fputs($fp, $seperator);

        mysqli_data_seek($sql, 0);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                $seperator = "";
                $comma = "";

                foreach ($row as $name => $value) 
                    {
                        $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('', '""', $value);
                        $comma = ",";
                    }

                $seperator .= "\n";
                fputs($fp, $seperator);
            }

        fclose($fp);
        echo "Your file is ready. You can download it from <a href='$filename'>here!</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There is no record in your Database";
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well? Have you put multiple inputs e.g. `name="select"` or `name="select[0]"`... etc?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="users.php"><input type="submit" name="check" />echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' value='$uid' /></td>";</form>

Comment: the checkbox is running in loop

Answer (score 0):

`$key` is only going to be the last value in the `foreach`. Give the following a go:

```
$id = $_POST['select'];
$key = "";
    foreach($id as $vals) {
        $key = $key . $vals . ",";
    }
$key = trim($key, ",");

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE uid IN ('$key')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: getting the first id only let me show you the response echo $key Response is this 1,2,3  | but why exporting data of only first id ?